# Pacemaker Promote Groups in Specific Order - Or Specify start last

Tags: centos, pacemaker, drbd, corosync

I have a group in Pacemaker which I need to start last. Ideally I'd like to know how to configure groups to start in an specific order, but I can't seem to figure it out, not sure if its possible. Seems like it should be, I love using groups as it helps me organize and makes reading what's going on in the config much easier.

What I'd like to do with 2 groups:

```
pcs resource group add ASTERISK-Group Asterisk FOP2

pcs resource group add SQL-Group varlibmysql sql_service

pcs constraint order promote SQL-Group then ASTERISK-Group
```

But it just says that SQL-Group doesn't exist.

Note: CentOS 7 Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong action in your ordering constraint. 'promote' should only be used on Master/Slave resources, use 'start' on your groups.

```
pcs constraint order start SQL-Group then ASTERISK-Group
```

Comment: Interestingly, I can't use this with pcs -f cibname constraint order start SQL-Group then Asterisk-Group. But I ran it directly on the cluster and it worked wonderfully! Thanks Matt.